# How to sort the array of objects using several keys at the same time?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects, each has `name`, `skill` and `talent` keys.
It looks like this:

```
 let defaultArray = [
  {name='person1', skill = 6, talent = 3},
  {name='person2', skill = 5, talent = 5},
  {name='person3', skill = 4, talent = 6},
  {name='person4', skill = 2, talent = 7},
  {name='person5', skill = 1, talent = 4},
  {name='person6', skill = 3, talent = 1},
  {name='person7', skill = 6, talent = 2}
]
```

I need to sort it so that I only have the array of the three best persons defined by their skills, like so:

```
let resultArray = [
  {name='person1', skill = 6, talent = 3},
  {name='person7', skill = 6, talent = 2},
  {name='person2', skill = 5, talent = 5},
]
```

As you see if someone's skills are the same (like for `person1` and `person7` in the `defaultArray`),
then persons are sorted by `talent` instead.

---

Can someone, please, help me make a concise function taking `defaultArray` as a parameter and returning `resultArray` taking into account that the `skill` and `talent` values can be completely random?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should not ask people to write code for you. You should first attempt this yourself, then if you have any problems, we will be glad to help. As a starting point, sort the array by talent then by skill.

Comment: You should showcase how much have you delved into figuring sorting & custom comparators in JS. If you are a newbie to JS, start here: [mdn reference on sorting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arr = [
    {name:'person1', skill : 6, talent : 3},
    {name:'person2', skill : 5, talent : 5},
    {name:'person3', skill : 4, talent : 6},
    {name:'person4', skill : 2, talent : 7},
    {name:'person5', skill : 1, talent : 4},
    {name:'person6', skill : 3, talent : 1},
    {name:'person7', skill : 6, talent : 2}
  ];
  

arr.sort((a, b) => (b.skill - a.skill) || (b.talent - a.talent));
console.log(arr)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```